# Maven/Eclipse Mark target directories as derived

Tags: eclipse, maven

Is there a way to tell maven to mark target directories as derived when using eclipse:eclipse 
I've searched stackoverflow but only found solutions with custom plugins but I'd like to do it with maven only.

Manually marking the directory is not an option, as it will be discarded everytime eclipse:eclipse is run.

Comment: Which Eclipse version? M2E Plugin?

Comment: Version: Kepler Service Release 1, Build id: 20130919-0819 I don't use m2eclipse, but plain mvn 2.1.0 from the commandline.

Comment: I don't post an answer cause you explicitly told that you don't want a plugin. But here is a plugin (sic) which may help you. Disclamer, I wrote it :) http://nodj.github.io/AutoDeriv/